# Make zoom on NSData or on CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, opencv, camera, zooming, avfoundation

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

This app will work with OpenCV and I have to make zoom on camera but this, it isn't available on iOS SDK, so I think to do it programmatically.

I have to do 'zoom' on every video frame. This is where I have to do it:

```
#pragma mark - AVCaptureSession delegate
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    /*Lock the image buffer*/
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    /*Get information about the image*/
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    //size_t stride = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

    //put buffer in open cv, no memory copied
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, baseAddress);
    // copy the image
    //cv::Mat copied_image = image.clone();
    _lastFrame = [NSData dataWithBytes:image.data
                                  length:image.elemSize() * image.total()];

    [DataExchanger postFrame];

    /*We unlock the  image buffer*/
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
}
```

**Do you know how to make zoom on a `NSData` or on a `CMSampleBufferRef`?**

Comment: Would the zooming be for the purpose of image display directly or for image manipulation of pixels and as such, you would need access to the zoomed pixels data? Also, what are you defining as a zoom: if I zoomed a 640x480 by 2, would that mean every pixel would be copied to the pixel next to it (x) and under it(y)?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put your picture into a CGImageRef, choose a square in that picture and draw it again to a normal size. Something like this (though there may be better ways):

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);


    CGImageRef smallQuartzImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(quartzImage, CGRectMake(200, 200, 600, 600));

    cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC4 );
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate( image.data, width, height, 8, cvMat.step[0], colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst );
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), smallQuartzImage);
    CGContextRelease( contextRef );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
```